# What is the meaning of map<string, int> m= {}; in C++?

Tags: c++

I was going through a program in C++. I am a beginner, so I was bit confused what's the meaning of this.

Problem was this:

https://www.codechef.com/problems/H1

I saw someone's solution and am confused what the meaning of 
`map<string, int> m= {};` is.

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/20124020

Comment: Its a null initializer, meaning its making the map start out empty. Theres a few differnt ways/syntax for this.

Comment: `={}` means: Intialize with empty data.

Comment: Make your question self contained please, don't require people to follow links to grasp what your problem is.

Comment: Templates are very useful to write something for everything only once. Here, map is written only once, but applicable for any type, including <string,int> version you looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map<Key, Value>` is an associative container that maps keys to values. See [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for full details.

`map<string, int> m = {};` invokes the default constructor of `map<string, int>`. In fact, `= {}` part is unnecessary `map<string, int> m;` does the same thing in a less verbose way.

Also, if both the default constructor and the initializer list constructors are available, `= {}` calls the default constructor.

Comment: @ShubhamGuptaGgps You may like to get a C++ book.

Comment: Can you suggest me a good one..  sorry if it was a stupid question

Comment: @Shubham Gupta Ggps - they are template arguments. They tell `std::map` the *types* to use for key and value.

Comment: Good books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @ShubhamGuptaGgps We keep a list of good books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list